# ImportError: cannot import name 'App' from partially initialized module guizero most likely due to a circular import

Tags: python, guizero

Querio hacer un proyecto con la libreria guizero y me sale este erorr ImportError: cannot import name 'App' from partially initialized module 'guizero' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\POO\guizero.py)

```
from guizero import App, Text
app = App()
text_1 = Text(app, text="on top")
text_2 = Text(app, text="below")
app.display()
```

Comment: Llamaste a tu py igual que el modulo?

Comment: A mi me funciona OK.

Comment: El codigo que me sale erorr es ese y nose como hacer

Comment: El problema es que tu ejecutable también se llama "guizero.py". Cambiale el nombre y estas listo.